# SQL group by days interval

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sample table here with the following columns and sample records. I want to be able to sum my column cases using with a specific date range (the helper column).

I want to get my results this way:

Sum all cases WHERE date range is in between 2022-03-23 - 2022-04-01 and so on.

| date range | Sum of Cases |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-23-2022-04-01 | 5 (sample result only) |
| 2022-03-24-2022-04-02 | 9 (sample result only) |

The logic of the date range is always n - n9 days.

I 've tried this type of query but it does not work, it there a way for me to get this without have to use a query to create another column?

```
SELECT Date, 
       sum([QUERY 1]) as "Reports  7 days prev", 
       sum ([QUERY 2]) as "Reports 7 days after" 
FROM REPORTS 
GROUP BY Date
```

Data:

| Date | BuyerID | Cases | Helper (Date Range) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4/1/2022 | 20001 | 2 | 2022-03-23-2022-04-01 |
| 4/1/2022 | 20001 | 1 | 2022-03-23-2022-04-01 |
| 4/2/2022 | 20002 | 3 | 2022-03-24-2022-04-02 |
| 4/5/2022 | 20003 | 5 | 2022-03-27-2022-04-05 |
| 4/7/2022 | 20004 | 6 | 2022-03-29-2022-04-07 |
| 4/7/2022 | 20005 | 9 | 2022-03-29-2022-04-07 |

[image]

Comment: sql-server or MySQl

Comment: What is your database, e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle?

Comment: i'm using MySQL

Comment: Tip: Don't post an *image of text*, just post the text. Posting images greatly limits how much help we can offer because we can't copy text and test your sample data from a screen shot. (It also tends to attract down votes).

Comment: thanks for pointing that out @SOS let me edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to get total cases for last X number of days? What does your initial data look like?

you can try something like:

Step 1: You aggregate all the cases for each date.

```
WITH CASES_AGG_BY_DATE AS
(
SELECT Date, 
       SUM(Cases) AS Total_Cases
FROM REPORTS
GROUP BY Date
),
```

Step 2: you aggregate the last 7 days rolling cases sum for each date

```
LAST_7_DAY_AGG AS
(    
SELECT Date, SUM(Total_Cases) OVER(ORDER BY Date ASC ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sum_of_cases,
LAG(Date, 7) AS 7th_day
FROM CASES_AGG_BY_DATE
)
```

Step 3: create final output and concatenate date and 7th day before that

```
SELECT Date, CONCAT(Date, "-", 7th_day), sum_of_cases
FROM LAST_7_DAY_AGG;
```

Comment: hi, yes. i'm looking to get total cases for last X number of days for each date available. so for today's date Apr 27th, my date range would be April 21st to April 27 for last 7 days and Apr 20th to Apr 26th for Apr 26th. my initial data is just the date, buyer_id, cases and I just created an additional CONCAT() for the helper column. let me try your answer, thank you very much!